# Trace on non-separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

In a textbook I am reading the trace on operators of a Hilbert space is considered. Since in the book it is generally not assumed that the Hilbert spaces are separable, I wonder how the trace is even defined on a non-separable space.

One possibility would be if an operator is non-zero only on a separable subset of the entire space, and it is of trace class in a separable Hilbertspace containing this subset you could define the trace to be the trace of the restriction onto this space. That this is well defined seems an easy enough exercise.

But this seems an extremely restrictive and unimaginative definition, is there another way?

Comment: Where do you need separability. Simply define $A$ to be trace class if $\sum_{e\in A} \langle |A|(e),e\rangle <\infty$ for some orthonormal basis $A$. One checks in the usual fashion that this is independent of the choice of orthonormal basis. You don't need the basis to be countable for this.

Comment: For the sum to be defined, does the part on which $<|A|(e),e> \neq 0$ have to be countable? So would we still be restricting the operator to be non-zero on a separable subset?

Comment: No. You can simply define it in terms of nets: For each finite subset $F\subset A$, define $$s_F = \sum_{e\in F} \langle |A|(e),e\rangle$$. Now the "series" converges if these "partial sums" form convergent net. If the sum is finite, then you are right - the set $\{e \in A : \langle |A|(e),e\rangle \neq 0\}$ must be countable.