# $F(H)$ is dense in $L^1(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is well known that the set of finite rank operators $F(H)$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is dense in the set of trace class operators $L^1(H)$. I am aware of the proof using the characterization of compact operators on a Hilbert space. However, I am interested in the provided solution which seemingly has a simpler solution.

> Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis and $p_n$ projection onto first $n$ coordinates. Then $|x|^{1/2}-|x|^{1/2}p_n$ converges to $0$ in the Hilbert Schmidt norm. This implies that $$\||x|-|x|p_n\|\leq \||x|^{1/2}\|_{H.S}\||x|^{1/2}-|x|^{1/2}p_n\|_{H.S}$$

First of all, are we assuming that $H$ is separable? Second, I thought we needed to show that
$$\|x-xp_n\|_{T.C}=\||x-xp_n|^{1/2}\|_{H.S}=\sum_{e\in E} \langle |x-xp_n|e, e\rangle \to 0
$$
so I do not understand how the inequality in the provided solution is supposed to imply this.

Comment: By the way, you technically need a square on the H.S. norm at the end of your question for the equation to be correct: $\|x - xp_n\|_{T.C.} = \||x-xp_n|^{1/2}\|_{H.S.}^2$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separability for anything.  See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427946/trace-on-non-separable-hilbert-spaces) for a discussion.  The trace on $L^1(H)$ will have at most countably many non-zero summands for any operator/choice of basis, but that doesn't mean the basis itself has to be countable.

I'll use the subscript 1 for the trace class norm and 2 for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm (which is typical for [Schatten norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)).  You're right that you need to show that $\|x - xp_n\|_1 \rightarrow 0$, but you can do that with the given inequalities.

First of all, note that $\|x - xp_n\|_1 = \|x(1-p_n)\|_1 = Tr(\sqrt{(1-p_n)x^*x(1-p_n)}) = \||x|(1-p_n)\|_1 = \||x| - |x|p_n\|_1$.  So a bound on the last expression is the same as a bound on the first.

Your quoted inequalities allow you to finish, since they give:
$$\|x - xp_n\|_1 = \||x| - |x|p_n\|_1 \le \||x|^{1/2}\|_2 \||x|^{1/2} - |x|^{1/2}p_n\|_2 \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: How do you get the last inequality?

Comment: Factor out an $|x|^{1/2}$ and then apply Hölder’s inequality (with $p = q = 2$). See Properties [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).